# Can I use TensorFlow GPU version without cuDNN, and how?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow1.13 GPU version (with cuda), and I do not want to use cuDNN to do the convolution due to some reasons. Anyone know how to do that plz?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use tensorflow GPU without CUDA because Keras is based on it. Tensorflow packs another library inside it that is called Keras which uses this dependency.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I mean without cudnn, I want to use TensorFlow with cuda but without cudnn.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense, the OP never mentioned Keras at all. And Keras does not depend on CUDA (the tensorflow backend does that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using TensorFlow 1.13 version, instead of Keras. TensorFlow 1.13 GPU version calls the conv and pooling in cudnn library. I want to use CUDA for the TensorFlow but doesn't want to use the cudnn library. There is a flag in use_cudnn.cc named "TF_USE_CUDNN" but I cannot simply disable cudnn by setting the flag as false. Therefore, I wanna know whether there is a way to disable the cudnn in GPU version TensorFlow 1.13